# How to compile a delegate taking one argument?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was fiddling with compiled delegates and tried to call `Serialize` and `Deserialize` functions in the following class using compile delegates (don't mind the names). I had success in calling `Serialize`, but not `Deserialize`. The problem seem to be I don't seem to understand how to pass the `string` argument to the `Func` object in the following code. Does anyone know a fix to my code (and brain)?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeString { get; }

    public SomeClass(string str)
    {
        SomeString = str;
    }


    public string Serialize()
    {
        return SomeString;
    }


    public SomeClass Deserialize(string str)
    {
        return new SomeClass(str + " - !!!!");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static class TypeSerializationCache<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<T, string> Serialize;
        public static readonly Func<string, T> DeserializeThatShouldBe;
        public static readonly Func<T, string, T> DeserializeOriginalFixed;

        static TypeSerializationCache()
        {

            const string SerializeFunctionToCall = "Serialize";
            var serializeFuncParameterValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "serializeFuncParameterValue");
            var serializeMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(SerializeFunctionToCall, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { }, null);

            var serializeCall = serializeMethod != null ? (Expression)Expression.Call(serializeFuncParameterValue, serializeMethod) : Expression.Constant(default(T), typeof(T));
            Serialize = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(serializeCall, serializeFuncParameterValue).Compile();


            const string DeserializeCallFunction = "Deserialize";
            var deserializeFuncParameterValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "DeserializeFuncParameterValue");                
            var deserializeMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(DeserializeCallFunction, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
            var deserializeArgument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "deserializeArgument");

            var deserializeCall = Expression.Call(deserializeFuncParameterValue, deserializeMethod, deserializeArgument);

             DeserializeOriginalFixed = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string, T>>(deserializeCall, deserializeFuncParameterValue, deserializeArgument).Compile();

             //To my great dismay, the following throws.
             DeserializeThatShouldBe = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, T>>(deserializeCall, deserializeFuncParameterValue, deserializeArgument).Compile();

        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var class11 = new SomeClass("XYZ");
        var class12 = new SomeClass("123");

        var class31 = TypeSerializationCache<SomeClass>.Serialize(class11);
        var class32 = TypeSerializationCache<SomeClass>.Serialize(class12);
        var class31d = TypeSerializationCache<SomeClass>.DeserializeOriginalFixed(class11, class31);
        var class32d = TypeSerializationCache<SomeClass>.DeserializeThatShouldBe(class32);
    }
```

**<edit:** I needed to come back (awake) and make this attempt to fix the number of parameters. Not quite what I was hoping for, ideally I'd like to use just the type parameter and the serialized string. Also, *duck talk* reminds me of [bug talk](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2009/06/01/debugging-net-applications-a-power-course-day-12/). :)

Aanyway, I'm still in search of the root fix, not just band-aid...

**<edit 2:** Now, the root fix appears to be in my brain and to understand one needs an instance for an instance method, or a static method. I think I got my ducks lined up and counted for after a good shut-eyes. My thanks to **Eric**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does anyone know a fix to my code

Show a programmer where the bug is, they fix the bug.  **Teach the programmer how to find the bug, and they stop posting their buggy code for other people to debug for them, saving everyone time.**

Obtain a rubber duck. Read this line **out loud** to the duck.

```
var deserializeFuncParameterValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "DeserializeFuncParameterValue");
```

Now read this line **out loud** to the duck.

```
Deserialize = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, T>>(deserializeCall, deserializeFuncParameterValue, deserializeArgument).Compile();
```

Now explain to the duck like the duck is completely ignorant of expression trees **why it is that the code is correct**.  Since the code is *not* correct, you should be unable to do so. The specific point at which you are unable to do so is either the bug, or a point where there is correct code that you cannot justify. Either way, you've learned something about the code, and probably you've found the bug.

Hint: **The error message is not wrong**. If you need to, read the error message out loud to the duck as well.

(The original poster has neglected to post the error message, which is "*Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration*".)

> (and brain)?

Rubber duck debugging works because it does an end run around the part of your brain that is stopping you from finding the bug.  Your brain wants to believe that the code you wrote is correct, and it is literally not allowing you to see the obvious problem. You read the code, your eyes glaze over a little bit, and it is "obviously correct".  Well no, it is not.

Explaining it to the duck forces your brain to re-examine the incorrect assumptions that led you to believe that the wrong code was "obviously correct".

Note that [it works for mechanical engineering problems and stuffed ducks too](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html).

Comment: Can this example be used with a stuffed kitten instead of a rubber duck? I don't like ducks, they're evil, and I'm not sure if the result will be correct with the kitten...

Comment: @Gusman: Try it, see if it works. I have heard that it works with giant stuffed moose heads as well.

Comment: Wow, nice! I'm going to kill now a moose and stuff it's head to test it! thanks!

Comment: Hmm, pardon my poor and boor choice of words. A better one would have been that can someone push me to right direction. My only defence is a moving train and unslept night, but let me sleep on this. I suspect this is something obvious. :)

Comment: @Veksi: Again: the error message is correct. The error message is "incorrect number of parameters" so the questions you should be asking yourself are "How many parameters is the correct number?" and "How many did I supply?" and "Are those two numbers equal?"

Comment: I have no doubt about that. I was gone to bed already, but now that I woke up, I scribbled the idea to here and fixed the number of parameters problem. It looks like I'm on the wrong level here, somehow, and I'd need to pass the parameter in some different manner.